# How can I use onclick method?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, mouse

I made object of window by javascript. And I want to add some functions to the windows object. But .onclick, .setattribute, and .addEventListener do not work with my object. Even mouse cursor also can not be changed when I give value of css or javascript. It is on 499 line of my source. Could you tell me why these do not work? Should I change language? Is it bug?

```
function seSizeValue(theNumOfWins,outlayerId){
        var seSizeValue;
        var seSizeValueId;
        seSizeValueId = "seSizeValueId" + theNumOfWins;
        seSizeValue = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById(outlayerId).appendChild(seSizeValue);
        seSizeValue.setAttribute("id",seSizeValueId);
        document.getElementById(seSizeValueId).setAttribute("class","seSizeValueCSS");
        document.getElementById(seSizeValueId).onclick = function(event) {seSizeChange();};

        return seSizeValueId;
    }
```

"""document.getElementById(seSizeValueId).onclick = function(event) {seSizeChange();};"""

This line does not work. I already tried to change '.setattribute', and '.addEventListener'.

There was no error. But it does not work.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4p8lZSEMXcqN0FzQTkyVW8wRGc/view

this is my full source.

It does not work on my source.

Should I use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I think so Save the window reference in a variable with a sentence like that

var new_window = window.open

is posible ser manually events in DOM subelements using jquery with On() method o directly with javascript.

Im not sure about that but I suggest a posible solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function defined as "seSizeChange" so when the onclick event fires, it's going to run a function that doesn't exist.

Also, when you call this "seSizeValue" function, are you calling it after the specified element has been loaded on to the document?

If not, the code won't be able to find the specified element.

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById(seSizeValueId).onclick = function(event) {seSizeChange();};
```

is definitely wrong.

See http://jsfiddle.net/2txugfq5/

Everything is working except fact that 'seSizeChange' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

John makes good points.

See here http://jsfiddle.net/hqw7ocwj/2/ , works fine. No changes to anything of importance from your code, apart from:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

and:

```
function seSizeChange() {
    alert("seSizeChange method fired.");
}
```

Main points:
1. Ensure your JavaScript is called only after the DOM is ready: $(document).ready(function{});
2. Make sure that the method in the function that the onclick refers to has been defined.